# Track Form Submissions with Google Analytics 4 to register conversions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I need to track the submissions of a form using Google Analytics.

On my website I already have Google Analytics (GA4) o track page views:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXX"></script>

<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){ dataLayer.push(arguments); }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXX');
</script>
```

The url of the page that contains the form is `/contact` but might be:

```
/contact?topic=inquiry&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=xyzzy&utm_id=12
```

And a simplified version of the form is:

```
<form x-data="send_message()" method="post">                
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <button class="action" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted the `submit` method runs:

```
export default function send_message() {

  submit() {

    fetch("/messages", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        // Show success message
      } else {
        // Show error message
      }
    })
  }
};
```

How to track the form submissions and with `UTM` or `Topic` parameters so I can measure conversions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to track the form submission as a conversion is necessary to:

1. Create a custom event:
   In the admin panel of your GA4 property go to "Events" > "Create Events" and create an event like this:
   [image]
2. Mark your custom event as a conversion:
   In the admin panel of your GA4 property go to "Conversions" > "New Conversion event" and paste the name of your custom event created in item #1 (must match)
3. This will only work if you turned ON "Form interactions" and "Enhanced measurement".
   To check this, in the admin panel of your GA4 property go to "Data Streams" > click on your data stream > click on the gear under "enhanced measument" options and check that "form interactions" is ON.